# How to auto forward incoming emails (rule based) into specific slack channel

Tags: slack, slack-api, google-groups, google-groups-api

i'm wondering how i can auto forward incoming emails (rule based - like from specific address) into specific slack channel.

I don't know if it matter but in my case the mail set on google-groups (running on gcp cloud)

can u assist?